# How does Magento 2 handle cross browser styling?

Tags: magento2, css, browser

I've seen modernizr in use on Magento 2 but so far I haven't seen any examples of fixing cross browser issues (and yet a lot of use of flex). The compatible browser list is quite merciless - is this why I haven't seen it handled as frequently?

What is the best practise for browser compatible css? Or targeting browsers / features specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't do an awful lot to handle it but that may be because they only support IE from 10+ ([as Luma and Blank had too many selectors for IE9 and below](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5126)) so it isn't so much of an issue.

### Body class

They do use the IE body class for styling, for example:

`magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less`

```
.page-wrapper {
    ...

    .ie10 &,
    .ie11 & {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

### Prefixes

They also use a few MS prefixes:

`magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_email-base.less`

```
//  Allow smoother rendering of resized images in Internet Explorer (such as high-resolution logo)
    img {
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    }
```

### iOS

There are also some references to iOS:

`magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_email-base.less`

```
//  Remove link color on iOS
    .no-link a {
        color: @text__color !important;
        cursor: default !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }
```

`magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/source/_reset.less`

```
html {
    //  Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling user zoom.
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

### Other

There is also the odd code here and there that handles it via markup:

**I've just noticed this is from the Zend Framework, my bad. I'll leave it here as it's still technically in Magento.**

`magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/ProgressBar/Adapter/JsPush.php`

```
protected function _outputData($data)
    {
        // 1024 padding is required for Safari, while 256 padding is required
        // for Internet Explorer. The <br /> is required so Safari actually
        // executes the <script />
        echo str_pad($data . '<br />', 1024, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT) . "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Any idea how it's getting ie11, etc? And if this goes lower?
Edit: Just read, ignore me.

Comment: @LM_Fielding - There are a few references to ie11 to, search `/vendor/magento` for `.ie11` and you should find a few. IE11 isn't too bad so I doubt there will be many. From what I can see they have tried to cater for IE9 and above. I can't see much for anything else.